# c# matching fixed properties on in memory data

Tags: c#

Guys this is racking my brain

I have a **slow** implementation in Linq that I need to speed up.

I need the fastest possible way to compare a large set of readonly data in memory (200,000) rows.

Each row has a name and 10 integers representing properties on the name

```
Brake   8 7 3 2 1 0 4 3 2
Skull   8 7 3 2 1 0 4 3 2
Napkin  3 0 5 3 2 1 3 1 0
```

Each item will never have more then 8 in any single property. So each value can fit nicely into a double

ex:

```
Brake:873,210,432
```

Now my problem is I need to compare these values to a maximum number for each field

ie:

500,000,000 would return the first 2 and

000,001,000 would only return Napkin because the other 2 don't have at least 1 in the 4th position.

I'm open to any soltuion that is as **fast** as possible. There will be a lot of comparisons so speed is the only thing I'm worried about here.

My current implementation would be something like this:

```
Items.Where(c => c.A <= 5).Where(c => c.B <= 0).Where(c => c.C <= 0)
.Where(c => c.D <= 0).Where(c => c.E <= 0).Where(c => c.F <= 0)
.Where(c => c.H <= 0).Where(c => c.I <= 0).Where(c => c.J <= 0)
```

Or (they both run about the same speed)

```
Items.Where(c => c.A <= 5 && c.B <= 0 && c.C <= 0
 && c.D <= 0 && c.E <= 0 && c.F <= 0 && c.H <= 0
&& c.I <= 0 && c.J <= 0)
```

Comment: Care to post your own implementation for review?

Comment: So you took 8 properties smushed them into 1 and its slow when you need to find info on just one of them. hmmm...

Comment: No I didnt mush them into one I'm just giving background information.

Comment: Any reason you mention 10 integers, and then list only 9 per item? If it's really only 9, then you can use an `int` rather than a `double`, which will probably speed up the (I assume) modulus division and lower your memory footprint. If it's 10 digits, then you can use a `long`, which still simplifies the math, but does not save any memory.

Comment: At some point there will more then the length of an integer sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Kyle my apologies I misunderstood

Comment: Do you always have patterns like 500000000 or is 511666818 possible?

Comment: From my tests, filtering 200,000 rows, when you store the values for each line in an array of `int`s takes about 500 ms. Is that too much for you?

Comment: @Conrad yes 511668818 is also possible

Comment: @svick yes because there could be thousands of calls

Comment: @Kyle: see my updated answer. It can be done much more quickly than I indicated in my original answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is represented by a structure that resembles this:

```
public abstract class Widget
{
  public string Name   { get ; private set ; }
  public byte[] Values { get ; private set ; }
}
```

Whether it's an array of bytes, or a bit field that you draw from is, I suspect fairly irrelevant to performance.

One approach would be to build 8 parallel arrays containing references to your widgets with each such array being sorted on a different value column. Lookup then consisted of a binary search for the desired values.

Another approach is to read your source data once, and populate an array of height-balanced binary search trees, whose key is the value of the desired column and whose value is the list of Widgets sharing that particular column value. You'll need one such search tree for each column. Obviously, this approach eats memory to get speed — lookup in a height-balance binary tree being a O(log *N*) operation. Using trees means that items can be added to and removed from the collection without imposing a lot of overhead.

Whilst you **could** write your own tree implementation, I'd rather not. Here is an implementation, using the [C5 Collections Library](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/) (something you should have in your toolbox anyway) since I hate having to invent the wheel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using C5;

namespace ConsoleApplication13
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            IEnumerable<Widget>  sourceData  = ReadWidgets();
            WidgetSearcher lookup = new WidgetSearcher( sourceData );

            // find all the Widgets where column 2 is >= 5 ;
            Widget[] results1 = lookup.Search( 2 , 5 ).ToArray();

            // find all the Widgets where column 0 is >= 3 ;
            Widget[] results2 = lookup.Search( 0 , 3 ).ToArray();

            return ;

        }

        private static IEnumerable<Widget> ReadWidgets()
        {
            //TODO: we need source data from somewhere. It gets provided here.
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }

    public class Widget
    {
        public const int ValueCount = 8;

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public byte[] Values
        {
            get
            {
                return (byte[])_values.Clone();
            }
        }
        private byte[] _values;

        public Widget( string name , byte[] values )
        {
            if ( name==null )
                throw new ArgumentNullException( "name" );
            if ( name.Trim()=="" )
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( "name" );
            if ( values==null )
                throw new ArgumentNullException( "values" );
            if ( values.Length!=ValueCount )
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( "values" );

            this.Name=name;
            this._values=values;
            return;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// private constructor for search instances
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="column"></param>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        private Widget( int column , byte value )
        {
            this.Name=null;
            this._values=new byte[Widget.ValueCount];

            this._values.Initialize();
            this._values[column]=value;

            return;
        }

        public class Comparer : IComparer<Widget> , IEqualityComparer<Widget>
        {
            private int ColumnToCompare;

            public Comparer( int colNum )
            {
                if ( colNum<0||colNum>=Widget.ValueCount )
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( "colNum" );
                this.ColumnToCompare=colNum;
            }

            #region IComparer<Widget> Members

            public int Compare( Widget x , Widget y )
            {
                return (int)x._values[this.ColumnToCompare]-(int)y._values[this.ColumnToCompare];
            }

            #endregion

            #region IEqualityComparer<Widget> Members

            public bool Equals( Widget x , Widget y )
            {
                return ( x._values[this.ColumnToCompare]==x._values[this.ColumnToCompare] );
            }
            public int GetHashCode( Widget obj )
            {
                return obj._values[this.ColumnToCompare].GetHashCode();
            }
            #endregion
        }


        internal static Widget CreateSearchInstance( int column , byte value )
        {
            return new Widget( column , value );
        }

    }

    public class WidgetSearcher
    {
        private C5.TreeBag<Widget>[] lookups;

        public WidgetSearcher( IEnumerable<Widget> sourceData )
        {
            this.lookups=InstantiateLookups();
            PopulateLookups( sourceData );

        }

        private TreeBag<Widget>[] InstantiateLookups()
        {
            C5.TreeBag<Widget>[] instance =new C5.TreeBag<Widget>[Widget.ValueCount];

            for ( int i = 0 ; i<instance.Length ; ++i )
            {
                Widget.Comparer widgetComparer = new Widget.Comparer( i );

                instance[i]=new TreeBag<Widget>( widgetComparer , widgetComparer );

            }

            return instance;
        }

        private void PopulateLookups( IEnumerable<Widget> sourceData )
        {
            foreach ( Widget datum in sourceData )
            {
                for ( int i = 0 ; i<Widget.ValueCount ; ++i )
                {
                    lookups[i].Add( datum );
                }
            }
            return;
        }

        public IDirectedCollectionValue<Widget> Search( int column , byte value )
        {
            Widget limit = Widget.CreateSearchInstance( column , value );
            return lookups[column].RangeFrom( limit );
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This is really cool Nicholas. Is there a way to chain the values Like say .Search(0, 3).Search(1, 2).Search(2, 3).Search(3, 0)

Comment: Also Nicholas small problem with your code. If I enter the same value for the Byte Array and a different name 7 times. It will return only the first object 7 times.

Comment: Nicholas you beautiful sob I could kiss u. Went from 84,000 ms down to 49. I used the treebag and chained it all the way down

Comment: This solves the single property search case (i.e. searching for `0050000000`), but what about multiple properties? That is, if you want to search for `7461834251`, doesn't this require 10 lookups and then 9 list intersections to get the final result? Or am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: @Jim this code doesn't solve anything actually. It doesn't even work. Using the Treebag with a comparer allowed me to have Trees of Trees with each tree being indentified by the count of properties @ that index.

Comment: Glad I could be of help B^) (and sorry about the bug -- I just cobbled that up off the top of my head). As far as making it a more fluent interface....there's probably a way to do that, but maybe you need to raise the level of abstraction a bit: i wasn't thinking about a general solution.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there's a better way than my original answer, but it requires 5 bits per item rather than 4 bits per item. I'll illustrate it with three items in a 16-bit value. You can extend it to your 10 items using the first 50 bits of a long integer.

Imagine that you're saving three 4-bit counters in a 16-bit integer. Each counter has an additional bit that's used for calculation (see below). So your Brake item with the first three counters would be:

```
       3     7     8
Brake 00011 00111 01000
```

Now, you want things that match "504", that is at least five items in the first column, any number in the second column, and at least four in the third column. That mask would be:

```
         4     0     5
Search 00100 00000 00101
```

Logically, we want to subtract the Search from the Brake, and know if all the required fields are greater than or equal to zero. That's where the extra bit comes in. If we set that extra bit on each of the fields, we have:

```
Brake 10011 10111 11000
```

Now, if we do a subtraction in this case we end up with:

```
Brake - Search = 01111 10111 10011
```

Note that the high bit in the leftmost field of the result is 0. This indicates that the number that was in that field of the Brake value was smaller than the value we were looking for.

Now, how to make this work in code. In my example, using `short`, I'd have:

```
short Brake = (short)((3 << 10) | (7 << 5) | 8);
short Search = (short)((4 << 10) | (0 << 5) | 5);

short CarryMask = 0x4210;  // sets the high bit in each field.
                           // corresponds to 0100001000010000

// This would have to be done for each value that you want to compare.
short MaskedValue = (short)(Brake | CarryMask);
short diff = (short)(MaskedValue - Search);
short rslt = (short)(CarryMask & diff);

// rslt should equal CarryMask
if (rslt == CarryMask)
{
    // All fields match
}
else
{
    // At least one field doesn't match
}
```

You can determine which fields don't match by looking at the bits in the `rslt`. Every fifth bit (i.e. bits 4, 9, and 14) should be 1. If the bit is 0, then that field didn't meet the minimum.

So to compare a single item, you have to do three operations and a comparison. That's going to be a whole lot faster than my earlier answer.

**Implementation**

The implementation below assumes that you have the 10 values for each name in an array of bytes. The first method, `CreateValue` builds a long integer that represents those 10 values.

```
long CreateValue(byte[] values)
{
    // probably should check here to ensure that values is 10 bytes long.
    long val = 0;
    foreach (var b in values)
    {
        // do error check. If b > 15, then this is going to fail.
        val = (val << 5) | b;
    }
    return val;
}
```

I'll assume that you have your data in some format where you can conveniently put the field values for each item into an array of 10 bytes. You'll want to add a `CombinedValue` property that holds the combined values. Or perhaps you have a parallel data structure to hold the combined values. Anyway, you have to do this loop once at program startup to create the data that you'll use for comparison (or perhaps update the value if you can update the individual fields).

```
foreach (var item in DataItems)
{
    byte[] values = GetValuesFromItem(item);
    // if you can't store it in the item, put it in a parallel array or list.
    item.CombinedValue = CreateValue(values);
}
```

I'll assume, too, that when it comes time to search, you can put the values you're looking for into an array of bytes and call `CreateValue` to get the combined value you're searching for. Now all you need is the method that will do the comparison.

```
// Carry mask has every 5th bit set.
// This is actually the mask for 12 values.
// That's okay, since nothing will affect those higher bits.
const long CarryMask = 0x842108421084210L;

bool ItemMatches(long itemValue, long searchFor)
{
    long maskedValue = itemValue | CarryMask;
    long diff = maskedValue - searchFor;
    long rslt = diff & CarryMask;
    return (rslt == CarryMask);
}
```

Searching your list, then, becomes very simple:

```
long searchFor = CreateValue(array_of_values);
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (ItemMatches(item.CombinedValue, searchFor)
    {
        // The item matches the criteria you specified
    }
}
```

Comment: This is giving me about a 60% improvement. I'm probably using it wrong. I have this on a function in a straight list. I want to implement this into some kind of hashtable or log(N) strutcture but I'm stumped right now.

Comment: @Kyle: Check my implementation, which is O(n). Offhand, I can't think of a way to improve on that.

Comment: @Kyle: A minor optimization. If you store the items with the `CarryMask` already in place, you can eliminate the first line of the `ItemMatches` method. The second line becomes `long diff = itemValue - searchFor;`